# Считать тектовый файл из Assets Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

Хочу считать тектовый файл из Assets, но никак не выходит
Код который в справке Microsoft не компилируется, подчеркивает Assets

```
using Android.Content.Res;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

     AssetManager assets = Forms.Context.Assets;
                string content;
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(assets.Open("AboutAssets.txt")))
                {
                    content = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
```

Comment: вот код нашел другой https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=windows

Comment: Это тот же код, я его там и брал.

Comment: а у меня другой открывается, например сразу AssetManager assets = this.Assets;

Comment: заработало с такой строчкой AssetManager assets = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets; и добавлением AboutAssets.txt в AndroidAsset в действиях при сборке.